# My Window 7 is not showing in booting

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

i am using window 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 at the same time. after update Ubuntu my window 7 is not showing in the boot loader plz help me

Comment: Try `sudo update grub` in terminal

Comment: If that doesn't work, use the tool Boot Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)